# Conditional join based on a table further down the line

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a MySQL query that left joins three tables in a row to the primary table, but does this conditionally based on a value on the last table being joined.  The two ways I'm trying to do it both have problems:

- Either not all the primary rows I need are shown
- Or I get some extra irrelevant rows in there.

The table structure is part of an existing system and I can't change it.  Also once I figure out the SQL I'm going to have to find a way of integrating this with its query system, so the simpler the SQL the better!

I'm going to put a lot of details down here, sorry this is such a long post but I thought better to include all the information.

Here's more info:

**Data model:**

There are users, courses and an intermediary content type which stores user information for each user on a particular course, known as a cui.
I need to see a list of all users, and if there is a cui for that user and course, to include it too.

In the database, the field contents of the cui are stored in separate tables and joined via the cui_id, which is part of the trouble.

**Stripped down database structure:**

- Primary table: user (fields: uid, name)
- Cui table: node (fields: cui_id)
- User field table (fields: cui_id, uid)
- Course field table (fields: cui_id, course_id)

**Joins**

```
user     user_field         node         course_field
----     ----------         -------      ------------
uid ==== uid          
name     cui_id =========== cui_id ===== cui_id
                                         course_id    = 202
```

**Attempted queries:**

The following queries are run on a small sample data set with the following users:

- User Two: Has a cui for the course queried against, and has cuis for
  other courses.
- User One: Has cuis for other courses but not for the
  one queried against.
- User Six: Has no cuis.

This first query is a conditional join on the last table, the trouble is it includes an extra row for user two which is not for the correct cui.
I didn't want to GROUP BY as I thought it wouldn't necessarily give me the correct row.

```
SELECT user.uid, user.name, field_user.cui_id,
field_course.course_id
FROM user
LEFT JOIN field_user
ON
user.uid = field_user.uid
LEFT JOIN node AS cui
ON
cui.id = field_user.cui_id
LEFT JOIN field_course
ON
field_course.cui_id = cui.id
AND
field_course.course_id = 202
```

Result:

```
uid     name        cui_id  course_id
---------------------------------------------
4       User One    772     NULL
5       User Two    434     202
5       User Two    771     NULL
35      User Six    NULL    NULL
```

The alternative is this one:

```
SELECT user.uid, user.name, field_user.cui_id,
field_course.course_id
FROM user
LEFT JOIN field_user
ON
user.uid = field_user.uid
LEFT JOIN node AS cui
ON
cui.id = field_user.cui_id
LEFT JOIN field_course
ON
field_course.cui_id = cui.id
WHERE (
field_course.course_id = 202 OR ISNULL(field_course.course_id))
```

Result:

```
uid     name    cui_nid     course_nid
---------------------------------------------
5       User Two    434     202
35      User Six    NULL    NULL
```

Trouble with that one is it leaves out User One, because User One does have other cuis, just not for the correct course.

So the question is, how do I get this?

```
uid     name        cui_id  course_id
--------------------------------------------
4       User One    772     NULL
5       User Two    434     202
35      User Six    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Why do you need the node table? Also, could you please put your test data as well?

Comment: put the whole structure of your db tables

Comment: All you say about the query you're trying to perform is "*I need to see a list of all users, and if there is a cui for that user and course, to include it too*" -- when you say "that user and course", to which course are you referring?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what a course is in this context, I'm trying to keep this question as generic as possible.  I've added a diagram of the joins above, basically I only want to join those three tables to the user if the field on the final table equals a certain value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really not that pretty but should do the trick:

```
-- Select to get all users irrespective of whether they have a row in field_course or field_user
SELECT user.uid, user.name, field_user.cui_id,
null as course_id
FROM user
LEFT JOIN field_user ON user.uid = field_user.uid
LEFT JOIN node AS cui ON cui.id = field_user.cui_id 
where user.uid not in
(
-- Inline view to get only users that have both a field_course & field_user row
SELECT user.uid
FROM user
INNER JOIN field_user ON user.uid = field_user.uid
INNER JOIN node AS cui ON cui.id = field_user.cui_id
INNER JOIN field_course ON field_course.cui_id = cui.id
where field_course.course_id = 202
)
union all
-- Select to get only users that have both a field_course & field_user row
SELECT user.uid, user.name, field_user.cui_id,
field_course.course_id
FROM user
INNER JOIN field_user ON user.uid = field_user.uid
INNER JOIN node AS cui ON cui.id = field_user.cui_id
INNER JOIN field_course ON field_course.cui_id = cui.id
where field_course.course_id = 202;
```

**EDIT**

Here is the table structure and data I used to test:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `node` (
`id` int(10) unsigned not null primary key
);

CREATE TABLE `field_user` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cui_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `field_course` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cui_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`course_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
);

insert into user (uid,name) values (4,"User One");
insert into user (uid,name) values (5,"User Two");
insert into user (uid,name) values (35,"User Six");

insert into node (id) values (771);
insert into node (id) values (772);
insert into node (id) values (434);

insert into field_user (uid,cui_id) values (4,772);
insert into field_user (uid,cui_id) values (5,434);
insert into field_user (uid,cui_id) values (5,771);

insert into field_course (uid,cui_id,course_id) values (5,434,202);
```

Comment: Ah thanks yes that does work, not sure I'll be able to implement that as part of the query system I'm using but I'll give it a go.  
For the benefit of others, I'd paraphrase this approach as: 
1) Select all the users who don't have a cui for the required course
2) Select all the users who do have a cui 3) Create a union of the two result sets.